# Problem sharing images from Photoshop Elements 10 to Flickr/Smugmug

Tags: flickr, cropping, photoshop-elements

I'm trialling PSE10 as a cheap way of getting good raw processing.

Whenever I crop/straighten an image via the 'raw' processing dialog and then upload the result to an online service (tried both flickr and smugmug so far) the *uncropped* image is uploaded.

Am I doing anything particularly stupid here, or is this a bug? (or another reason to pony up for Lightroom!)

I haven't tried cropping the image via the 'full' PSE editor, but I have a feeling that would work.

Answer (score 1):

First, an overview of how to crop a RAW file in Camera Raw -
The steps I take are:

Open Camera Raw Dialog> Select Crop tool> Highlight Area to crop> Hit Enter after selection is what you would like> Open Image

At this point, you should see the cropped image appear in the work area. Exporting via Save As or Save For Web will export the cropped image.

**Now here comes the piece that I think you are getting stuck on - If I go and reopen the RAW file at this point - it automatically shows the cropped image already selected. It does not show the crop window or the full image.** I have to select Crop> Clear Crop to remove that crop I previously added.

Comment: I'm not doing "Save As" or "Save For Web". I hoped the built-in flickr uploader should be smart enough to do that itself. Anyhow, just picked up LR3 at a very reasonable £99, and very happy with that so far.